# Intercept and analyze responses from Zend_Rest_Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, frameworks

I used Zend Framework 1.11 to make a REST web service in PHP using the Zend_Rest_server class but I wasn't able to intercept and analyze the responses from Zend_Rest_server instances before these are sent to the clients.

To make the REST web service I use this snippet of code:

```
$server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
$server->setClass('Ws_dummy', 'dummy');
$server->handle();
```

Is there a method to log responses because I need to analyze them and I wasn't able to find a way to solve this need.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

P.S. For example in SOAP web services I can do this:

```
$server->setReturnResponse(true);
$response = $server->handle();
```

or

```
$server->handle();
$response = $server->getLastResponse();
```

and analyze the responses

Answer (score 0):

You can log Requests like this:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/path/to/logfile');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->info( Zend_Debug::dump( $_REQUEST, 'Request-Dump', false );
```

You should do that before the Rest_Server handles the Request.
If you got further Questions - just ask :-)

---

Edit (added some useful information):

It may be helpful to understand that Zend_Debug::dump() method wraps the PHP function var_dump(). If the output stream is detected as a web presentation, the output of var_dump() is escaped using htmlspecialchars() and wrapped with (X)HTML pre-tags.

---

Edit #2:

You can return the Response of Zend_Rest_Server with:

```
$server->returnResponse(true);
```

before $server->handle().

---

Edit #3:

Be aware:
If I've read everything right you need to send the Headers by urself if you are returning the Response.
You can get/+set the Headers with:

```
$headers = $server->getHeaders();
foreach( $headers as $header ) header( $header );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is "request", for request is all ok, I need the Answer sent to client, for ex. with  Zend_Json_Server() I can use  $server->getResponse()->getResult()

Comment: I've edited the Code again. This should work to get the Response.